# How to calculate oracle column data with group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to calculate different columns from different tables.
i am trying to get my required result from my code but the result 
give me twice same rows of data

i have 3 tables in my oracle database `rolls_purchase`,`rolls_issue`,`rolls_consumption`

```
CREATE TABLE ROLLS_purchase(
V_ID INT,
ENT_DATE DATE,
ENT_TIME DATE,
QUALITY VARCHAR2(25),
ROLL_QTY INT,
ROLL_SIZE INT);

CREATE TABLE ROLLS_ISSUE(
V_ID INT,
ISSUE_DATE DATE,
ISSUE_TIME DATE,
QUALITY VARCHAR2(25),
ROLL_SIZE INT,
ROLL_QTY INT,
TO_PO VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE ROLLS_consumption(
V_ID INT,
ISSUE_DATE DATE,
ISSUE_TIME DATE,
QUALITY VARCHAR2(25),
ROLL_SIZE INT,
ROLL_QTY INT,
ROLL_USED INT,
LEFT_ROLL INT
);
```

when i purchase rolls and put data into my `rolls_purchase` table,i got result
correctly,after that i use `rolls_issue` form for issue roll then my form coding  doing well, 3rd step is when a user consumed the roll,if there are some left and returned to me,i need to add them back when i use my code then the result gives me twice same rows like as below.

```
select x.quality,x.roll_size,sum(x.roll_qty)as 
"TOTAL_ROLL",NVL(SUM(I.ROLL_QTY),0)
from rolls x, rolls_issue I
where x.quality is not null
group by x.quality,x.roll_size,I.ROLL_QTY,I.QUALITY;
```

above codes result is

```
        quality           size  t.roll    used
 FLOUTING 100 GSM         44    150       40
 FLOUTING 100 GSM         44    150      20
 FLOUTING 125 GSM         36    50        40
```

i need this result ,if issue my rolls then above code calculate my rolls group by and sum them only one row like below

```
     quality           size  t.roll    used
 FLOUTING 100 GSM         44    150       60
 FLOUTING 125 GSM         36    50        40
```

Comment: I cannot see a common column among `rolls_purchase` and `rolls_issue` to be used within the join condition. And does `rolls ` mean `rolls_purchase` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only `p.quality,p.roll_size` within grouping clause(I just replaced the alias `x` with `p`)

Use such a query with join :

```
select p.quality, p.roll_size,
       sum(p.roll_qty) as "Total Roll", nvl(sum(i.roll_qty), 0) as "Total Used"
  from rolls_purchased p
  join rolls_issue i
    on p.issue_id = i.v_id
 where p.quality is not null
 group by p.quality, p.roll_size
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `group by` before `join`ing:

```
select quality, roll_size, r.total_roll,
       coalesce(ri.total_issue, 0)
from (select r.quality, r.roll_size, sum(r.qty) as total_roll
      from rolls r
      group by r.quality, r.roll_size
     ) left join
     (select ri.quality, ri.roll_size, sum(ri.qty) as total_issue
      from rolls_issue ri
      group by ri.quality, ri.roll_size
     ) ri
     using (quality, roll_size)
```